Error: Failure when receiving data from the peer
I'm currently working on a CV management website using Node.js, Express.js, MySQL, and Sequelize. I've set up two forms, one for job seekers and one for recruiters, and defined corresponding models using Sequelize.
However, when I test my API using an API tester with the URL http://localhost:3001/forms/jobseeker and provide a JSON example of a jobseeker form in the request body, I encounter the following errors:
In the API tester: "Error: Failure when receiving data from the peer."
In the terminal: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')".
I modified the code to test with only one form, and it was working fine. Can anyone help me identify and fix the issue?
this is the code of my main file "index.js":
const express = require ("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
const db = require("./models");

//Routers
const formRouter = require('./routes/forms');
app.use("/forms",formRouter);

db.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
    app.listen(3001,()=>{
        console.log("Server running on port 3001");
    });
});

and this is the code for forms "forms.js" in folder "models":
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const JobSeekerForm = sequelize.define("JobSeekerForm", {
        // Fields for JobSeekerForm
    });

    const RecruiterForm = sequelize.define("RecruiterForm", {
        // Fields for RecruiterForm
    });

    return { JobSeekerForm, RecruiterForm };
};

and this is the code for routes "forms.js" in folder "routes":
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { JobSeekerForm, RecruiterForm } = require("../models");

// Route for job seekers
router.post("/jobseeker", async (req, res) => {
    const form = req.body;
    await JobSeekerForm.create(form);
    res.json(form);
});

// Route for recruiters
router.post("/recruiter", async (req, res) => {
    const form = req.body;
    await RecruiterForm.create(form);
    res.json(form);
});

module.exports = router;


Your potential problem in this line: const { JobSeekerForm, RecruiterForm } = require("../models"); - make sure, you really get the  JobSeekerForm and RecruiterForm
